# Intercepting console output which originated from Tess4J

Tags: java, stdout, tesseract, stderr, tess4j

I am trying to intercept the red `Empty page!!` message that gets printed to my screen when using `Tess4J`.  I wrote a short interceptor class that overrides `print` and `println` and replaced `stdout` and `stderr` to check for this string:

```
private static class Interceptor extends PrintStream {
    public Interceptor(OutputStream out) {
        super(out, true);
    }
    @Override
    public void print(String s) {
        if ( !s.contains("Empty page!!") )
            super.print(s);
    }
    @Override
    public void println(String s) {
        if ( !s.contains("Empty page!!") )
            super.println(s);
    }
}
```

I tested the class:  It works and suppresses any `Empty page!!` that I write to `stdout` and `stderr`.  I do not succeed in catching the `Empty page!!` message from `Tess4J` that gets printed to my console in red though.  My question:  How can I intercept and suppress this message?

Thanks a bunch.

[image: Screenshot Eclipse]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to emulate Tesseract's `quiet` command-line option, which has `debug_file /dev/null`.

```
api.setVariable("debug_file", "/dev/null");
```

or

```
instance.setTessVariable("debug_file", "/dev/null");
```

Comment: Hello nguyenq: Firstly, thanks a bunch for `Tess4J`.  It is an awesome program. Secondly, could you please tell me a little more about the variable `api` you are referring to here? Thanks!

Comment: It refers to the low-level `TessAPI`. You can also use the high-level one. More info about the [`quiet`](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_supress_tesseract_info_line?) option.

Comment: Thank you, nguyenq.  I am still confused, however.  I tried implementing it and it did not change anything for the output.  Could you please provide me a short code snippet of how to implement it?  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Can you attach a sample image that outputs "Empty page!!", so I can try out? Tks.

Comment: I am looping over a bunch of image files and some of them are empty.  I would like to avoid all that "Empty Page!!" output.  This is an example file that creates "Empty Page!!": https://www.dropbox.com/s/njppgbn5bwbnaui/193_351.jpg?dl=0  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Try the code above -- it will suppress the warning messages.