# Suppress Warning on Console when using Tess4j for OCRing

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, suppress-warnings, tess4j

Help in Suppress Warning- "**Warning. Invalid resolution 1 dpi. Using 70 instead.**" when using Tess4j for OCRing

Hi All, I would like to suppress the warning  thrown out in Console when using Tess4j for OCRing. Please help.

Tesseract uses Leptonica for some image processing internally and Leptonica thows this on console.

TIA

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894575/intercepting-console-output-which-originated-from-tess4j

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't suppress this warning, since this is from Leptonica which is used by tesseract. It suppresses other tesseract warnings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Workaround: Not from Leptonica(lept4j) but from Tesseract(tess4j) way. Setting the Resolution if the resolution of the image if it is less than 70.

```
    TessAPI1.TessBaseAPISetImage2(handle, pix);
    //To remove the warning message "Warning. Invalid resolution 1 dpi. Using 70 instead." Setting the resolution
    int  res = TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIGetSourceYResolution(handle);
    if (res < 70) 
        TessAPI1.TessBaseAPISetSourceResolution(handle, 70);
```